# Could you explain the mixture of many kinds of operands below? (C++)

Tags: c++, std-function

I've checked someone's code through a tool, and it said that there is a problem here:

```
policyCallback = callback;
```

I cannot find the problem since I'm a beginner.
Could you give me a hint or guide to translate it?

The entire code is below.

```
std::function <void (std::vector<std::string> resources)> policyCallback;

namepace nsp {
class Manager {
public:
  Manager(const std::string &str);
  virtual ~Manager();

  template <typename FuncType>
  void registerPolicyActionCallback(FuncType callback) {
    policyCallback = callback;
  }
};
} //namespace nsp

namespace nsp{
class Manager;
}

class SomeAPIs {
public:
  void policyActionCallback(std::vector<std::string> param);
};

int main() {
  nsp::Manager *rManager; 

  rManager->registerPolicyActionCallback(std::bind(&SomeAPIs::policyActionCallback, this, std::placeholders::_1)); 
}
```

Comment: Where is declaration of variable policyCallback?

Comment: Aha overlooked, first line! You expect vector of strings as callback and than use template function which takes any type and assigns to it? Weird.

Comment: @Radek Could you explain your saying more detail?

Comment: Is your question what is wrong with the code? Or are you asking specifically what is wrong with the line policyCallaback = callback?

Comment: @nabia My real question is what wrong the specific line is with, but please let me know if the code has somer problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Besides some obvious errors in the code, the main problem preventing you from achieving what you want is the way in which you are calling `std::bind`.

Firstly, your code declares `policyActionCallback(/*...*/)` private in `SomeAPIs`. Now while you can call any member function via a pointer to it, regardless of it being public, protected, or private, only members and friends can create a pointer to a private member function. So unless you call `std:bind` from within the API itself, or a friend of the API, you will only be able to bind to public member functions of the API. For the sake of demonstrating a working concept, I will assume that the functions you want to use for callback are all public members of the API.

Secondly, to bind a member function using `std::bind`, you need to provide a reference to the function (which you did), as well a reference (or pointer) to **an instance of the class to which the member belongs**, which you have not done.

Therefore, since the function you want to bind to is a member of `SomeAPIs`, you need to give a reference to an instance of `SomeAPIs`. I'm assuming that you intended `this` to be a pointer to the `nsp::Manager` instance, which, as I have just explained, is the wrong object to provide a reference to.

Additionally, your use of the `this` keyword is incorrect. Taken from cppreference, `this` can appear in the following contexts

1. Within the body of any non-static member function, including
   member initializer list
2. Within the declaration of a non-static
       member function anywhere after the (optional) cv-qualifier sequence,
       including dynamic exception specification(deprecated), noexcept
       specification(C++11), and the trailing return type(since C++11)
3. Within default member initializer (since C++11)

Since your use of `this` fits non of the above, the compiler gives:

```
error: invalid use of 'this' in non-member function
```

Here is working code for what you are wanting to achieve. Note how `std::bind` is now used. (I have added a constructor for `Manager`, removed the virtual destructor since manager does not have any virtual function, made the function in `SomeAPIs` public so that `std::bind` can receive a pointer to it, and deleted the `nsp::Manager` pointer which now is declared on the free store):

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

std::function <void (std::vector<std::string> resources)> policyCallback;

namespace nsp {
    class Manager {
    public:
      Manager() {};
      Manager(const std::string &str) {}

      // Don't know why this is virtual when this isn't a base class?
      // virtual ~Manager();

      template <typename FuncType>
      void registerPolicyActionCallback(const FuncType callback) {
        policyCallback = callback;
      }
    };
} //namespace nsp

class SomeAPIs {
    public:
      void policyActionCallback(std::vector<std::string> param) {
          for (const auto& p : param) {
              std::cout << "SomeAPIs : " << p << "\n";
      }
    }
};

// Another API for illustration
class SomeOtherAPI {
    public:
      void policyActionCallback(std::vector<std::string> param) {
          for (const auto& p : param) {
              std::cout << "SomeOtherAPI : " << p << "\n";
      }
    }
};

int main() {

    // Sample resource vector for demonstration
    std::vector<std::string> resources = {"one", "two", "three"};

    // Gets rid of uninitialization error -- alternatively declare on stack
    nsp::Manager* rManager = new nsp::Manager; 

    // You need instances of an object to bind to member functions
    SomeAPIs        api1;           
    SomeOtherAPI    api2;

    // Use the first APIs function as callback
    rManager->registerPolicyActionCallback(std::bind(&SomeAPIs::policyActionCallback, &api1, std::placeholders::_1));
    policyCallback(resources);

    // Use the second APIs function as callback
    rManager->registerPolicyActionCallback(std::bind(&SomeOtherAPI::policyActionCallback, &api2, std::placeholders::_1));
    policyCallback(resources);

    delete rManager;
}
```

Here is a [live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6d44af1471e994b5).

Comment: OMG! It's so kind of you! Thanks a lot. I'll try to fix the code refer to your comments. BTW, compiler said like this below. Is it related to your comments?
1. policyCallback = callback;
--> no_matching_operator_function: no operator "=" matches these operands

Comment: No problem. Please see the live demo, for a working solution, maybe you can see the difference between a working solution and whichever one is giving the error.

Answer (score 0):

The snippet you provided is badly extracted copy. It confuses because the line `resourceManager->registerUMSPolicyActionCallback(std::bind(&SomeAPIs::policyActionCallback, this, std::placeholders::_1));` has argument value `this`, it means it was called inside of a class. There should be pointer to instance of `SomeAPIs`.

What i meant in the comment is declaration of method `registerPolicyActionCallback`. It is not necessary to be a template when `policyCallback` cannot be anything but the only type `std::function <void (std::vector<std::string> resources)>`;

Anyway all the code looks good. You wrote you used tool to check code, what tool? Does it supports C++11 properly?